# Change Mysql Column date format and Perform Query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

For Example

`select date_format(date(credit_date),'%Y-%m-%d') from product where date(credit_date) >= date '2012-11-02' and date(credit_date) <= date '2013-11-02'`

How to Fetch the Column From ***Date1*** To ***Date2***

And Db Structure is

```
           +-----------------------------------------+
           | credit_date                             |
           +-----------------------------------------+
           | 21/09/2013                              |
           | 22/09/2013                              |
           | 23/09/2013                              |
           | 24/09/2013                              |
           | 25/09/2013                              |
           | 26/09/2013                              |
           | 27/09/2013                              |
           | 28/09/2013                              |
           +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is the datatype of credit_date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like your credit_date is a varchar type with another date format, if so try this:

```
select date_format(str_to_date(credit_date,'%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as dt
  from product 
 where str_to_date(credit_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= '2012-11-02'
   and str_to_date(credit_date,'%d/%m/%Y') <= '2013-11-02'
```

The default format for mysql is Y-m-d you don't need to convert it on the where clause. Unless your database is configured to have a specific format. As your `credit_date` seems to be a varchar you have to convert it first to date then test it.

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b379/9